# bromobenzene and NaOH reaction at high temperature and pressure

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, nucleophilic-substitution

> Find the product of the following reaction
>
> [image]

Note that the carbon marked as a star is a special labelled carbon which may be considered as a $\ce{C-14}$ isotope

The given answer is (c)

Why would the product in option (b) form ?
I know that it proceeds via S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism but is there some sort of benzyne reaction where we would get the product in option (b) ?

Comment: It is similar to dow's process, which takes place via Sn Benzyne mechanism

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is, as mentioned in the comment by `@Jayadithya`, that given the reaction conditions, the explicit «marking» a carbon atom as $\ce{^{13}C}$ (instead of the *typical* $\ce{^{12}C}$ / $\ce{^{13}C}$ according to the general isotopic distribution for this element) *does not* introduce a significant site selectivity for the reaction of the intermediate benzyne:

[image]

Thus, one anticipates an equal molar ratio of products formed along pathway a), and b).  It is not the kinetic H-D isotopic effect you may observe e.g., with the $S_N2$ reactions